# .NET remoting issue when .net framework versions are different in client and server

Tags: .net, .net-remoting

We have a .Net Remoting service that was created using Framework version 1.1. One of the service calls return an ActiveReports.Document (reporting components) object. I can consume the service from a client created using .Net framework 1.1, but when I try to consume it from a client created using .Net framework 2.0 or 4.0 or 4.5, I get a SerializationException with message - "Cannot find member name System.Globalization.TextInfo.". Below is a comparison of the two client apps.

[image: Comparison of the two client apps]

I can say that the issue happens in serializing complex objects between the client and server when framework versions are different, but not sure what options are available to fix it. Upgrading the remoting service is not an option at this point. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeneos/archive/2006/03/15/552315.aspx) talks about a patch for the serialization issue. But it applies to Win2k3 server. Our server is already running Win2k8 R2.

Any pointers?